# Use delegate with autofac func

Tags: dependency-injection, delegates, autofac, cpu-usage

I'm using autofac to resolve dependance like this:

```
      builder.Register<IConfigurationFactory>(c =>
            new ConfigurationFactory(
                c.Resolve<ICacheManager>(),
                c.Resolve<IConfigurationManagerWrapper>(),
                c.Resolve<IDbContextResolver>(),
                "Registration"))
            .SingleInstance();
```

but i have CPU problems with this declaration :
[image]

How can I use func delgator for dependance resolution to ameliore peformance?

Regards

Comment: How can that be a performance problem? Your factory is registered as singleton. In other words, that delegate will only be called once!

Comment: Also take a look at this article from Mark Seemann about [Composing Object Graphs with Confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest that you decompose that statement into it parts, so that you can see the performance of each part:

```
builder.Register<IConfigurationFactory>(c =>
    {
        var cm = c.Resolve<ICacheManager>();
        var cmw = c.Resolve<IConfigurationManagerWrapper>();
        var dcr = c.Resolve<IDbContextResolver>()

        return new ConfigurationFactory(cm, cmw, dcr, "Registration");
    })
        .SingleInstance();
```

Reprofile that and see which of those statements is taking up the most time.

Answer (score 0):

I reprofile now and i have this result:
 [image]